# How to simulate a situation when non-empty Transaction Log file will be added to the SQL Server Full Database backup file

Tags: sql-server

I created a test database "StoredData" with a single table:

```
CREATE DATABASE StoredData 
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'StoredData', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\StoredData.mdf')
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'StoredData_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\StoredData_log.ldf')
GO

ALTER DATABASE [StoredData] SET RECOVERY FULL

GO

USE StoredData
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Users
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Then I inserted 3 records into that table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Users (Id, Name)
VALUES (1, 'John'),
       (2, 'Giovanni'),
       (3, 'Anna')
```

After that I run this query to have some active transactions:

```
DECLARE @i INT = 0;

WHILE @i < 1000
BEGIN

    IF(@i%10 = 0) BEGIN TRAN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Users
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM dbo.Users

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01';  

    IF(@i%10 = 9) COMMIT

    SET @i = @i+1
END
```

During the last query execution I'm trying to do full database backup:

```
BACKUP DATABASE StoredData 
TO  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\StoredData_FullRecovery_Uncompressed.bak' 
WITH FORMAT, NO_COMPRESSION
```

Then I'm looking into the backup file content:

```
RESTORE FILELISTONLY 
FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\StoredData_FullRecovery_Uncompressed.bak'
```

And I'm getting zero log file inside backup:

```
LogicalName:       StoredData_log 
BackupSizeInBytes: 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Database backups don't backup the log file.  They backup the database.  All the database pages are read and copied to the backup file.  But since it's an online backup some of the pages may be modified after they are copied to the backup (either by checkpoint, a subsequent transaction or by the rollback of an uncommitted transaction).  So the backup file will also contain the log records necessary to recover the database to a consistent state at the point in time that the backup completes.

The backup file also contains the metadata about all the database files, including the log files because RESTORE will recreate all these files.  That's what you're seeing in the file list, and since log file wasn't backed up, the BackupSizeInBytes for that file is 0.

To see the amount of log records included in the backup, take a backup during a long-running transaction and compare the database file's BackupSizeInBytes to the size of the backup file on disk.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on here:

1: The database is effectively in simple recovery mode when doing your modifications, since you never did your first full backup after creating the database.

2: The column BackupSizeInBytes seems to be 0 for all ldf files, quite simply, even when there is log records in there. The documentation is vague for this column, so it difficult to say whether it is by design or not.